# $http error method doesn't catch 400 error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Any clue $http's error method did not catch 400 bad request?

```
$scope.submit = function (type) {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/example.com',
          params: {
            type: type.type
          }
        })
        .success(handleNewParameters)
        .error(handleError);
      };
```

This is an old bug, I faced it once. Should I refactor all my success and error to then method?

Comment: Are you using any custom interceptors? If so, this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423983/angular-js-http-doesnt-catch-the-promise-error

Comment: Are you using interceptors in you application?

Comment: See also: http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/AngularJS-HTTP-Service-Success-Handler-400-Response-Code-and-Interceptors/

Answer (score 2):

If you have implemented Interceptors, then if the response status is 400 , you have to forward the promise..

So make sure you have this code in the end:

```
return $q.reject(rejection);
```